# Lenovo Legion Y530 Laptop Fans Not Turning On (i7-8750H processor running Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, fan, temperature

I have a new Lenovo Legion Y530 laptop with an i7-8750H processor. I have two solid state drives installed, one for Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and another for Windows 10. While in Windows 10 the laptop fans are working fine. However, while in Ubuntu I have not heard the fans come on at all. I have not really done anything except surf the web trying to figure out why my fans are not coming on.

I have installed sensors and it shows that fan1 is always at 8 rpms, which is odd because I was physically watching the fans when it said they were at 8 rpms and they were not moving at all. The six processor core temperatures are sitting around 38-48 Celsius.

I also installed hardinfo and it is not detecting any cooling fans or temperatures under Devices->sensors.

I am assuming this is either a driver issue or I am just not really working the processor enough for the fans to kick on.

So, I am wondering if there is a tool for testing the fans on a laptop and if there is a way to check that I have the latest drives for my hardware?

Comment: well actually, its just Fn + Q

Answer (score 1):

You can start and stop fans with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> manually. If it works, there is nothing to worry about.